# CSS tooltip not showing on top of all elements (no javascript)

Tags: html, css, hover, tooltip, show

How do I show a tooltip on top of all HTML elements?

**http://jsfiddle.net/Fk79x/**

```
<div class="wrapper">Lorem ipsum dolor 
   <div class="tooltip">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I added 4 new IDs in your HTML DIVs

```
<div class="wrapper" id="test1">Lorem...
<div class="wrapper" id="test2">Lorem...
<div class="wrapper" id="test3">Lorem...
<div class="wrapper" id="test4">Lorem...
```

And added this new CSS:

```
#test1 {
    z-index:40;
}
#test2 {
    z-index:30;
}
#test3 {
    z-index:20;
}
#test4 {
    z-index:10;
}
```

DEMO Here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/totallytotallyamazing/qH9za/)

Comment: your jsFiddle is not different from mine (z-index has no effect)

Comment: @VitaliyHayda my change is working in Firefox but just checked and its not working in safari and chrome. I will look closer.

Comment: @VitaliyHayda This should hopefully meet your expectations. I tested it in FF, Chrome, Safari, and Opera this time.

Comment: @VitaliyHayda You're welcome I'm glad I could help! But if you could please click the up arrow next to my Answer I would Greatly Appreciate it! For correct protocol see this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers PS: You can vote on Comments as well.